# KVO not working for Settings.bundle value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to observe the value change of a PSSliderSpecifier that is in a child pane, but it only works on iOS 9 simulator.

This is the code I'm using in the AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(
        self,
        forKeyPath: UserDefaultsAccess.UserDefaultsKeys.SliderValue,
        options: [.new, .initial, .old],
            context: nil)
        return true
    }

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    if keyPath == UserDefaultsAccess.UserDefaultsKeys.SliderValue, let change = change, let newSiliderValue = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Float {
        foo(sliderValue: newSiliderValue)

    }
}
```

`observeValue` is never called.

The new value is always saved, but I can't get any notification

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct to observe value changes from a settings bundle.

May I suggest to verify that `UserDefaultsAccess.UserDefaultsKeys.SliderValue` is identical with the `Identifier` specified in the settings bundle?

Here is a simple standalone example project that shows observing a user default from the settings bundle in action: https://github.com/ralfebert/UserDefaultsExample . Both on simulator and device I get a change event when switching back to the app from the settings app. Maybe trying it out in isolation gives you an idea what might be different/causing the problem in your project.

Probably not related to your issue: When I used the code snippet to reproduce the problem, the only problem I had is that calling `super.observeValue` caused a "An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled" crash - super should not be called when the value change has been handled.